# How to Alternative ul li create color change for the sub nodes

Tags: javascript

[image]
I have ul li for parent node has black color and sub node of ul li has green color , their sub child node alternative color to black for ul li how to write the html css and js for this condition.how to handle nested ul li alternative color change

I try to jquery for ul li for odd and even, add the class and styles for the class but it is not workingnswer properly

**Answer:**

```
  if ($(".sitemap-list")) {
             $('ul').find('li').each(function () {
                  var nestingLevel = $(this).parents('ul').length;
                 if (nestingLevel >= 2) {
                     var textColor = (nestingLevel % 2 === 0) ? '#004f39' : '#32363D'; // Alternating colors                      
var fontweight = (nestingLevel % 2 === 0) ? '600' : '600';                     $(this).find('a').css('color', textColor); 
                    $(this).find('a').css('font-weight', fontweight);                                     } 
            });    
     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code seems to be on the right track, but there are a couple of adjustments you can make to achieve the desired alternating colors for the nested ul li elements. Also, I noticed that you are using font-weight with the same values for both cases; you might want to adjust that based on your requirements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Your Title</title>
      <style>
        /* Define the default color for the top-level li elements */
        ul.sitemap-list > li > a {
          color: black;
          font-weight: 600;
        }
    
        /* Define the default color for the nested li elements */
        ul.sitemap-list ul li > a {
          color: green;
          font-weight: 600;
        }
      </style>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          if ($(".sitemap-list")) {
            $('ul.sitemap-list').find('li').each(function () {
              var nestingLevel = $(this).parents('ul').length;
    
              // Adjust the color based on the nesting level
              var textColor = (nestingLevel % 2 === 0) ? '#004f39' : 'black';
              
              // Adjust the font weight based on the nesting level
              var fontweight = (nestingLevel % 2 === 0) ? '600' : '400'; // Adjust as needed
    
              // Apply styles to the anchor element
              $(this).children('a').css('color', textColor);
              $(this).children('a').css('font-weight', fontweight);
            });
          }
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul class="sitemap-list">
        <li><a href="#">Top Level 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Level 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Level 1-2</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Level 1-2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Level 1-2-2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Top Level 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Level 2-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Level 2-2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```